# Launching Browser in end user machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have an internal ASp.NET MVC application which receives requests from an external system.The request looks something like this:

http://test.com/abc/showinfo/12345678990

Controller Action

```
[Route]
public ActionResult Showinfo(string somenumber)
{
if (somenumber.Contains("1234"))
    // Launch Chrome Browser
else
// Launch IE Browser
}
```

I tried with Process.Start(url ), its works fine in my localbox but fails in Dev server.

Is it possible to Launch a browser in end user system? if yes then please let me know the steps.

Comment: I guess the "internal" bit is important.  If spammers had the ability to open a browser on anyone's machine...

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "end user System"?

Comment: @derpirscher its web based application, so we have to launch the browser in user system.

Comment: So the request to your server is made by an external system (not a browser but some other service I presume). How do you determine on which machine you want to open the browser? Or is it the same machine from which the request originated? Is the sw creating the request under your control?

Comment: @derpirscher its the same machine which makes request.

Comment: What is the external system? Is it on the end user machine?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to Launch a browser in end user system?

Yes.

You can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to do it. But do note that if you impersonate credentials, it will send the password over the network in plain text.

```
psexec \\marklap c:\thebrowserpath\thebrowser.exe
```

References:

- http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/common-ways-run-programs-remote-computers
- http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://google.com");
```

You can replace http://google.com with your custom url

Comment: this one doesn't work in user system. It works only on local system

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible with your solution, but I think it would be more sensible to open a browser on the client as reaction to an answer from your service, i.e. the following workflow

1. The client sends a request to your server
2. Your server processes the request and constructs and answer. This answer contains the URL and the desired browser
3. The server sends the answer back to the client
4. The client receives the answer and checks for the URL and the desired browser
5. The client starts the desired browser with the URL

Depending on the client system (is it some sort of custom application/service?) opening the a new browser could be quite simple (`Process.Start()` or similar). If the whole thing runs in a browser, it could also be just opening a new tab (if it's the same browser). Opening an alternative browser may be tricky, but could be possible for instance in Chrome with Native Messaging (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)